# Creating five media players with many text views and buttons

Tags: java, performance, beginner, android

I'm wondering if there is a way to make my code more efficient? Perhaps by using loops or something similar?

I have posted the code below. Please tell me how I can make it more efficient.

P.S.: I'm new to Java programming so no hate please :)

```java
final TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
final TextView textview2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
final TextView textview3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
final TextView textview4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
final TextView textview5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
final TextView textview6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
final TextView textview7 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
final TextView textview8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
final TextView textview9 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView9);
final TextView textview10 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView10);

mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.nyaaw);
mp_pilla = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.pillabli);
mp_slua = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.slua);
mp_aaa = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.aaa);
mp_keften = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.keften);

count = Integer.parseInt(readFromFile());
textview.setText(count + "");
textview2.setText(cost + "");
textview3.setText(cost * 2 + "");
textview4.setText(cost * 10 + "");
textview5.setText(cost * 40 + "");
textview6.setText(cost * 100 + "");
textview7.setText(cost * 200 + "");
textview8.setText(cost * 600 + "");
textview9.setText(cost * 2000 + "");
textview10.setText(cost * 5000 + "");

button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
button2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton2);
button3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton3);
button4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton4);
button5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton5);
button6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton6);
button7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton7);
button8 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton8);
button9 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton9);
button10 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton10);

resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
disableSound = (Button) findViewById(R.id.disableSound);

ImageButton buttonsak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
ImageButton buttonsak2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton2);
ImageButton buttonsak3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton3);
ImageButton buttonsak4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton4);
ImageButton buttonsak5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton5);
ImageButton buttonsak6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton6);
ImageButton buttonsak7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton7);
ImageButton buttonsak8 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton8);
ImageButton buttonsak9 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton9);
ImageButton buttonsak10 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton10);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for more cleaner code. Loops and arrays are good, but this is better for readability

> VIEW LISTS
>
> You can group multiple views into a List or array.

```
@Bind({ R.id.myButton, R.id.myButton2, R.id.myButton3... })
List<ImageButton> buttonsList;
```

Try [butterknife](https://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) library

Comment: Better for readability but I would suggest him to improve his skills on some more basic things (such as loops). :)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can set user-friendly names for your views.

Second, you can create your own views and move your initial code in it:
[Android developer guide: create custom view.](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html)